# Replace data from server with data from local storage if it exists - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, local-storage

I know this might seem like a very basic question but I am still a beginner and trying to figure this out.

I have created a webpage containing a form in Django. Right now the form comes prefilled with a few values and the user has to fill in the rest.
It has different sections like education, work experience, basic info, etc and the user can add or delete multiple sections in education. The form data is ultimately stored in a JSON.
Right now every time a user clicks on add or delete the data manipulation happens in the frontend but just so that the changes reflect in the page I have to send it to the backend and reload the page.

FRONT END DISPLAY FORM CODE:

```
<h2>Technical Skills</h2>
{% for item in resume.techskill %}
        <fieldset>
        <div class="tech"></div>
        <legend>Technical Skill {{ forloop.counter }}</legend>
        <label for="skillName{{ forloop.counter }}">Skill Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="skillName{{ forloop.counter }}" name="skillName{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.skill_name }}"><br><br>
        <label for="expertise{{ forloop.counter }}">Expertise:</label>
        <input type="text" id="expertise{{ forloop.counter }}" name="expertise{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.expertise }}"><br><br>
        <label for="yearOfExp{{ forloop.counter }}">Year of Experience:</label>
        <input type="text" id="yearOfExp{{ forloop.counter }}" name="yearOfExp{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ item.year_of_exp }}"><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="deleteTechSkill('{{forloop.counter}}')">Delete Technical Skill</button><br><br>
      </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
<div id="techskill">
    <button type="button" onclick="addTechSkill()">Add Technical Skill</button>
</div>
```

ADD Tech skill code

```
function addTechSkill() {
  formData = generateJson();
  const techSkillItem = {
            skill_name: "",
            expertise: "",
            year_of_exp: ""
        };
  formData["techskill"].push(techSkillItem);
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/app/newPage',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
  },
    async: true,
    success: function() {
        // alert('technical skill added');
        window.location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

Delete Techskill code:

```
function deleteTechSkill(index) {
  formData = generateJson();
  techskill = formData['techskill'];
  cleaned_techskill = techskill.splice(index-1, 1);

  json_data = JSON.stringify(formData)

  $.ajax({
    url: '/app/newPage',
    type: 'POST',
    data: json_data,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
    },
    async: true,
    success: function() {
      // alert('Technical skill deleted');
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

I need a solution to reload the page with the updated form without sending the entire JSON to the backend and then bringing it back to the front end.
I am using Django Framework, with html and javascript for frontend code.